# How I can make a block fixed?

Tags: html, web

I am trying to make my site adaptive to different screen size.So,you can see my problem in this video,I have tried relative,absolute positions + flex-box...nothing help...A block moves to the top of site..How I can fix this block?It should change a size,but it should move to the top of site.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybHQ1CVr6fs

```css
@charset "utf-8"

*{
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;
}


body{
 width:98%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 margin-left: 1%;
 margin-right:1%;
 font-size: 1em; 
 font-family: "FF Meta Serif" Serif;
 line-height: 120%;
}

footer,#page-wrap:after{
content: "";
display: block; 
}

#page-wrap{
 min-height: 95%;
 position: relative;
 
}



#logo{
 float:left;

 

}

img.logo{
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}

img.icq{
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

#menu1{
 float:left;
 margin-left:10%;
 width:50%;
}

li{
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
}

li.first{
 padding-left: 5%;
}

li.second{
 padding-left: 25%;
}

li.third{
 padding-left: 25%;
}
#support{

 float:left;
 width: 15%;


 line-height: 120%;
 margin-left: 10%;
}

span.icqnumber{
 font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 color:#009a00;
    font-weight: bolder;
    line-height: 0%;
}

#supporttitle{
 
 width:80%;
 float:right;
 margin-right: 10%;
}
span.support-worktime{
 font-family: 'Times New Roman',Times,serif;
 color: #999999;
 font-size:1em;
 font-weight: 250;
}

.my-flex-container{
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-moz-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
-o-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;

position: absolute;
margin-top: 5%;
overflow: none;

}

.my-flex-block1{
 
}

.my-flex-block2{
 background:#efefef;
}

p.slogan1{
 font-family: 'Times New Roman',Times,serif;
 font-size:2em;
 line-height: 5%;
}

p.slogan2{
 font-family: 'Times New Roman',Times,serif;
 font-size:2em;
 line-height: 5%;
}

#loginform{
 border-collapse: collapse;
 
 


}

h3{
 text-align:left;
 padding-left: 5%;
}

form{
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 5%;
 
}

input.login-field{
 width: 90%;
}


input.loginbutton{
 margin-left: 72%;
 
 background-color: #9b9999;
 color:#fff;
 padding-top: 0px;

}

input[type="text"]{
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}

p.forgot{
 color:gray;
 text-decoration: underline;
 margin-top: -10%;
 margin-left: 6%;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 padding-left: 1%;
}

span.remember{
 margin-left: -2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta name="keywords" content="">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <title>PROFIT-CENTER.RU</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
 <header>
 <div id="logo">
  <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
 </div>
  <div id="menu1">
  <ul>
     <li class="first"><a href="#">Условия</a></li>
      <li class="second"><a href="#">Поддержка</a></li>
   <li class="third"><a href="#">Форум</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="support">
  <img src="icq.png" alt="icq" class="icq">
  <span class="icqnumber">361855340</span>
 <div id="supporttitle">
  <span class="support-worktime">Служба поддержки 24/7</span>
 </div>
 </div>
</header>   
<div class="my-flex-container">
 <div class="my-flex-block1">
  <p class="slogan1">Заработай на своих</p>
        <p class="slogan2">сайтах больше!</p>
   </div>
 


 


    <div class="my-flex-block2">
    <h3>Вход</h3>
     <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="text" name="login" value=""  class="login-field">
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="login" value="" class="login-field">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="remember">Запомнить меня</span>
  <input type="button" name="login" value="Войти" class="loginbutton">
  <div class="forgot">
   <p class="forgot">Я забыл пароль</p>

  </div>
 </form>
 </div> 
  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please make your code a little more concise to show the problem. There is too much other code around it.

Comment: I talk about block with form

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the float on the `header`. Since it mostly contains floated elements (which are taken out of the flow of the document), any element coming after it will occupy its space.

You can read about different ways to clear/contain the floats [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-4).
I have used the clearfix technique below.

```
.clearfix::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    height: 0;
    clear:both;
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8" * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  width: 98%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "FF Meta Serif" Serif;
  line-height: 120%;
}

footer,
#page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

#page-wrap {
  min-height: 95%;
  position: relative;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
}

img.logo {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

img.icq {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#menu1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 50%;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li.first {
  padding-left: 5%;
}

li.second {
  padding-left: 25%;
}

li.third {
  padding-left: 25%;
}

#support {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  line-height: 120%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

span.icqnumber {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #009a00;
  font-weight: bolder;
  line-height: 0%;
}

#supporttitle {
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

span.support-worktime {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 250;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.my-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 5%;
  overflow: none;
}

.my-flex-block1 {}

.my-flex-block2 {
  background: #efefef;
}

p.slogan1 {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 5%;
}

p.slogan2 {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 5%;
}

#loginform {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

h3 {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5%;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 5%;
}

input.login-field {
  width: 90%;
}

input.loginbutton {
  margin-left: 72%;
  background-color: #9b9999;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

p.forgot {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: -10%;
  margin-left: 6%;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding-left: 1%;
}

span.remember {
  margin-left: -2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <title>PROFIT-CENTER.RU</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-wrap">
    <header class="clearfix">
      <div id="logo">
        <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
      </div>
      <div id="menu1">
        <ul>
          <li class="first"><a href="#">Условия</a></li>
          <li class="second"><a href="#">Поддержка</a></li>
          <li class="third"><a href="#">Форум</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="support">
        <img src="icq.png" alt="icq" class="icq">
        <span class="icqnumber">361855340</span>
        <div id="supporttitle">
          <span class="support-worktime">Служба поддержки 24/7</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="my-flex-container">
      <div class="my-flex-block1">
        <p class="slogan1">Заработай на своих</p>
        <p class="slogan2">сайтах больше!</p>
      </div>






      <div class="my-flex-block2">
        <h3>Вход</h3>
        <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
          <input type="text" name="login" value="" class="login-field">
          <br>
          <input type="password" name="login" value="" class="login-field">
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox">
          <span class="remember">Запомнить меня</span>
          <input type="button" name="login" value="Войти" class="loginbutton">
          <div class="forgot">
            <p class="forgot">Я забыл пароль</p>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```